# Modern Webpack template on Rails 5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

I have downloaded [this Adminator template](https://github.com/puikinsh/Adminator-admin-dashboard), which is modern npm/yarn Webpack theme. As stated in the template's homepage, install instructions are:

```
> git clone https://github.com/puikinsh/Adminator-admin-dashboard.git adminator
> cd adminator
> npm install
> npm run dev
```

And it is working like a charm.

Now my question is, how can I implement it to Rails 5.1+? It should use webpack support like this when creating a new app:

```
> rails new myapp --webpack
```

Isn't that a support for SPA only? I still want Rails to render my pages old way.

Where should I put all the template assets to, as they are installed as node_modules by `npm install` in the original template?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can render Rails views the old way and just insert Webpacker components wherever you like with the `javascript_pack_tag` (info [here](https://github.com/rails/webpacker#usage)):

```
# app/views/lists/index.html.erb
<div id='app'></div>
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'app' %>


# app/javascript/packs/app.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.use(VueResource)

Vue.component('to-do', {
   template: '<table class="table"><tr v-for="item in list" :key="item.id">...</tr></table>',
   data: function () {
     return {
       list: []
     }
   },
   mounted() {
     this.get()
   },
   methods: { 
     get: function () {
    this.$http.get('/list')
        .then(response => {
      this.list = response.body
    }, response => {
      console.log('no good')
    })
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '<to-do></to-do>'
})
```

Sprockets assets can exist alongside Webpacker assets, but Webpacker by default serves entry points from `app/javascript`, so if you want Webpacker to serve the assets you should but them there. The paths shouldn't need adjusting, you can serve Sprockets assets from `/vendor` or `/assets`, and Webpacker by default will serve from `app/javascript`.

BTW, I think Rails 5.1 and the Webpacker gem prefer `yarn` over `npm` but that might not make much of a difference.

You can use [foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) with a `Procfile` to run both `rails s` and `webpack-dev-server` in the same terminal window.

```
# Procfile
rails: rails s
node: webpack-dev-server
```

Comment: Yes, I know that, but that is not my question. If I understand correctly, webpack is replacing assets, right? So 1) where should I put the javascript and style files from the template (can I put them into vendor folder?) and 2) how should I adjust the paths? 3) after all this, I just run npm install to install node_modules and call rails s in one terminal and npm run dev in another one??

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Will try it. Obe more question - Should I put also images and fonts to /app/javascript as well to keep references ok? Whole content of the template’s /src/assets folder (https://github.com/puikinsh/Adminator-admin-dashboard/tree/master/src)?

Comment: I haven't had to solve that myself, but putting them relative to the main `app.js` for whatever components of that dashboard repo you're using seems like a decent start to me.